# constraints of collection view cells inside another collectionview

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, nslayoutconstraint

I have created custom class for UICollectionView. And I want to put another Collection view into first one class's cell.

```
import UIKit

class ModeCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
    }


    let modeCollection : UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .cyan
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return collectionView
    }()

    func setupView(){
        backgroundColor = .red

        addSubview(modeCollection)
                addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:[v0(180)]-20-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": modeCollection]))

                addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-25-[v0(180)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": modeCollection]))

                addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-30-[v0(160)]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": modeCollection]))

                addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-95-[v0]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": modeCollection]))

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

This code works fine, but I wonder if it is possible  to use constraints as I am using them in other project:

modeCollection.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: .centerXAnchor).isActive = true
modeCollection.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
modeCollection.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
modeCollection.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 49).isActive = true

Problem is that there is no "view" in my new custom class and I don't have anything to refer to ...

Comment: You can probably do your setupViews inside your UICollectionViewCell subclass's layoutSubviews().

Comment: @SWAT inside my parent UICollectionViewController class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating constraints to `view`, you create constraints to `self` which will refer to `UICollectionViewCell` itself (`ModeCell` in your case).